# How to build a map of top level nodes and their children

Tags: scala

```
case class Node(id: Int, children: Set[Node])

val topLevel = Node(1, tlChildren)
val topLevel2 = Node(2, tl2Children)

val nodes = Set(topLevel1, topLevel2,..)
```

I want to create a map of the topLevel id's, and the value to be a list of all the id's of the children.

```
val map = Map[Int, List[Int]] = ..
```

So with this map, given any id, I can figure out what the top level id is.

How can I generate this map given the above Node class and nodes hierarchy?

I can get the top level nodes like this:

```
val topLevelNodeIds = nodes.map(n => n.id)
```

But not sure that is helpful because I need to use that in a recursive call.

Comment: Spot the assignment?  You need to find all the ids in a tree. That's all the ids in all the children, + the one in this node. To find the ids in a child node, that's all the ids in its children, + its own id. To find all the ids in one of its children, that's all the ids in its children + ....  See the pattern? You stop when your node has no children. You already know how to find the "list" of ids of that..

Answer (score 1):

First we will define auxiliary method for traversing `Node` recursively and collecting all ids:

```scala
def collectIds(nodes: Set[Node]): List[Int] = 
  nodes.map(_.id).toList ++ nodes.map(_.children).map(collectIds).flatten
```

Now we can simply map each `Node` to result of the method above:

```scala
val topLevelNodeIds = nodes.map(n => n.id -> collectIds(n.children)).toMap
```

Comment: This isn't tail recursive is it?

Comment: try adding the `@tailrec` annotation to this and see if it still compiles

Answer (score 1):

In order to do it in tail recursive way we would need to use BFS algorithm:

```
case class Node(id: Int, children: Set[Node])

val topLevel = Node(1, Set.empty)
val topLevel2 = Node(2, Set.empty)

val nodes = Set(topLevel, topLevel2)

@tailrec
def tailRecursiveSolution(buffer: List[Node],
                          visited: Set[Node] = Set.empty,
                          acc: Map[Int, List[Int]] = Map.empty): Map[Int, List[Int]] =
  buffer match {
    case top :: bottom if !visited.contains(top) =>
      val children = top.children
      tailRecursiveSolution(
        children.toList ::: bottom,
        visited + top,
        acc + (top.id -> children.map(_.id).toList)
      )
    case top :: bottom =>
      tailRecursiveSolution(bottom, visited, acc)
    case Nil => acc
  }
```

Now for each level we use `tailRecursiveSolution` and are getting required mapping. So all we need to do is fold the result from each level:

```
val result: Map[Int, List[Int]] = 
      nodes./:(Map.empty[Int, List[Int]]) { case (acc, root) => acc ++ tailRecursiveSolution(List(root)) }
```